# google-script - hide/show a dynamic range of columns

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet where every day a new column gets added with:

`sheet.insertColumnAfter(6)`

now i want to show/hide the columns starting at `column(7)` up till the last column of the sheet (which is a dynamic value).

i had the following thought and no idea why it doenst work:

```
function Historyausblenden() {
  var bereich = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var letzte = bereich.getLastColumn();
  bereich.getRange("G",letzte).activate();
  bereich.getActiveSheet().hideColumns(bereich.getActiveRange().getColumn(), bereich.getActiveRange().getNumColumns());
  bereich.getRange('F:F').activate();
}
```

It seems that getRange doesnt accept `var letzte`.

The errorcode says: "Methode getRange(string,number) not found!"

Why? What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues in your code.

1. You can't call `getLastColumn()` on a spreadsheet.
2. String concatenation in javascript is most easily done with `+` (e.g. `"G" + letzte`).
3. You can't activate a range without first selecting the sheet.

Lastly, you don't really need to activate to accomplish what you're trying to do, but you may have another reason for doing so.

Try this instead (and make sure you're selecting the correct sheet in the third line):

```
function hideHistory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastColumn = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  var startColumn = 7;
  sheet.hideColumns(startColumn, lastColumn-startColumn+1);
}
```

Comment: thank u very much that works perfectly. could u quickly explain to me why i cant call `getlastcolumn()`on a spreadsheet? i dont quite get it. the documantation just says "Returns the position of the last column that has content. " And what does my script have to to with javascript? (newbie here :) )

Comment: @RolandVreden Glad it worked. Please consider marking the answer as accepted. `getLastColumn()` can be called on a _sheet_, but you were attempting to call it on the spreadsheet. Just like in my code above, you need to get more specific before calling that function. Google Apps Script is based on JavaScript, which is to say that it's basically all JavaScript.